# WP_Query when meta_query value compare to array?

Tags: mysql, arrays, wordpress, serialization

I am trying to query posts with `meta_query` filter but the problem is I have stored multiple user ID's on custom field and I can't figure out how to filter the posts.

So the custom field is multi select box, and it saves ID's of selected users.

Now on the front end I want to query posts by checking if currently logged in user is in the list of selected users.

The query looks like this:

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'music',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC',
                    'meta_query'    => array(
                        array(
                            'key'     => 'manager',
                            'value'   => get_current_user_id(),
                            'compare' => 'LIKE',
                        ),
                    )
        );

      $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This would work if I have single user ID in the field. But value of `manager` is an array.

EDIT: To add a bit more info, the value of the field is saved as serialized array so the value in database is:

`a:2:{i:0;s:1:"2";i:1;s:1:"5";}`

The value to compare is just currently logged user id so it would be `5` for example.

If current user `5` is in serialized data query the post.

Answer (score 1):

Meta values are strings, so you can't build query where they behave like an array.
For WP_Query there is IN operator, but that is for vice-versa cases (when meta_value should be inside the given array).

So, to achieve your goal you can use some SQL. Find matched posts using SQL, then pass found post ID-s to WP_Query.

```
global $wpdb;
$sql="SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
      WHERE meta_key='manager' 
      AND meta_value like '%:".'"'.esc_sql($user_id_here).'"'.";%'";
$found_posts=$wpdb->get_col($sql);
if(empty($found_posts))$found_posts=[0];

$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'music',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'post__in'=>$found_posts
        );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: I don't know if this is just accident or actually working solution but your idea seems to work directly into $args like this: 
'value'   => ':"'.get_current_user_id().'";', 
'compare' => 'LIKE',

Comment: no. you mix up haystack and needle.  LIKE means meta_value LIKE user_id. But you need vice versa, you need user_id like meta_value. 
my solution with SQL works 100% for such cases.